# Why would script call round_any despite not being explicitly called?

Tags: r, debugging

I've been struggling with this script for the past month and I still haven't been able to answer this question. I know round_any is used in the plyr package but I don't even load it. I checked all my other packages using ls("package: ") and they don't have this function. Nothing else I find online has been able to point me in the right direction. In browser () I am able to see my type is double [4] (S3:integer64). Am I better off just changing my class from integer64 or finding out how to remove round_any?

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..2 = across(...)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Problem while computing column `Property Count`.
Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'round_any' applied to an object of class "integer64"
```

Edit:
This .r file contains all the functions and I have another .r file that calls them.

Argument/Call

```
market_stats_table = key_market_stats(historical_stats, historical_stats_by_class, report_quarter)
```

Function

```
  total_stats = stats_combined %>% 
    rename(`Net Absorption` = `Net Absorption QTD - Total`, 
           `Net Absorption YTD` = `Net Absorption YTD - Total`,
           `Construction Deliveries` = `Construction Deliveries QTD`) %>% 
    filter(Submarket %in% submarket_order) %>% 
    mutate(Submarket = factor(Submarket, levels = submarket_order, ordered = T)) %>% 
     arrange(Submarket)  %>% 
     # glimpse()
     mutate(across(c(`Direct Vacancy Rate`, `Overall Vacancy Rate`, `Overall Availability Rate`), scales::percent, accuracy = .1),
            across(any_of(sum_vars), 
                   scales::dollar, accuracy = 1, style_negative="parens", prefix=""),
            across(any_of(c("Full Service Gross Asking Rate", "Lease Rate")),
                   scales::dollar)) %>%
     select(Submarket, all_of(stat_order))
   market_stats_table(total_stats, 
                      cell_width = if_else(property_type == "Office", 1.05, .9), 
                      cell_height = if_else(property_type == "Office", .33, .27),
                      submarket_order,
                      totals)
 }
```

structure

```
structure(list(Market = c("Los Angeles", "0.4", NA, "0.5", "0.3", 
"New York"), `Property Count` = c("New York", "0.3", NA, "0.2", 
"0.9", "New York"), C = c("Chicago", "0.1", NA, "0.4", "0.3", 
"DC"), D = c("DC", "0.7", NA, "0", "0.2", "DC"), e = c("Miami", 
"0.8", NA, "0.2", "0.1", "Los Angeles")), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please show your code and also the `dput(head(yourdata))`.  Even if you are not calling the fucntion explicitly, there must be some function that calls it.  Without showing your code or data, we can only guess

Comment: @akrun that makes sense, thanks for responding I'll edit

Comment: @akrun I had to make a mock structure of what the data looks like as I was having trouble even bringing out the combined stats due to object errors. Let me know if that helps

Comment: The mock structure shows all columns to be character class as there are some character values in the top and bottom row.

Comment: I was able to re-create the error with mock structure using the same format, instead of class integer64 error I get a class error. If it's easier to see the re-created bug I can just append

Comment: that is a different error because your columns are character

Comment: oh boy I am lost then. I will have to figure out how to show you the header. stats_combined is made using three different sources using bind ()

Comment: I assume that your original error is based on the `integer64`.  If you could change the column class to numeric, it may work

Comment: was able to figure it out, thank you for helping @akrun. For anyone who wants to know I used stats_combined$"Property Count" <- as.numeric(as.character(stats_combined$"Property Count"))